# Nodejs + expressjs get http response as Buffer

Tags: node.js, express, httpresponse

I would like to send a Buffer through Http response, but on the client I receive it as string instead of Buffer. I use expressjs router, as below code

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const buf = new Buffer('Hello world');
  console.log(buf); // gives me <Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64>
  res.send(buf); // gives me 'Hello world' 
});
```

In the above code my expected result was Buffer () but I get the String output 'Hello World.

Someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Client don't know nothing about NodeJS `buffer`, so it can't use it.

Comment: What _exactly_ did you expect to receive? The hexadecimal representation of the buffer contents?

Comment: Buffer content something like this <Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64>

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in Express doc, http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

> When the parameter is a Buffer object, the method sets the Content-Type
>   response header field to “application/octet-stream”

Depends on your browser, some may download the response as a file (such as Chrome), some may read the stream and display the content directly (such as IE11).